# how to compare contents of two images?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have been struggling to find a proper image comparison technique. I have a directory in my system with couple of pictures and I am trying to recreate those pictures with same same objects, same lighting and same camera position. I want to know whether the correct camera frame is same as mentioned reference image.

for example, assume, we have a camera mounted in a fixed position, we took a picture  using that camera and stored that picture with named 'reference.jpg', now when i run this image comparison algorithm, without changing the camera orientation or any of the surroundings, the algorithm should return the correlation between the referenced image and the current frame, in this scenario it must return something like 1 as nothing is changed and everything is same.

Until now i have been using SSIM technique, although the precision of the technique is very bad, for example if i take a picture and then run SSIM technique in a loop, the deviation between the correlation foctor is very high somewhere like it says 0.72 or so which is very bad for precision.

Comment: Looks like you want to compare the images pixel vs pixel. For that you can use MSE or PSNR which is calculated using MSE. Note: These are not the best techniques for image comparison but in your case I think they should be fine.

Comment: You can also use Normalized Cross Correlation which also has the added benefit of getting a value between -1 and 1.

Comment: Are you sure about PSNR for this application ? lets assume i have an object with holes drilled  on it in a pattern which is assymterical over y axis. When turnover the object with 180 degree and take a picture of the back side of the object, wouldn't the PSNR be same in both the cases ? as net noise and net pixel intensity for all the pixels combined is same ?

Comment: Try NCC. That should be fine.

Comment: Thank you . Can you please help me clear out why exactly this is happening ? when two pictures are taken by the same camera, at the same orientation and location and with same lightning consecutively, shouldn't MSE be zero ? instead in my case it kept gaining. The longer i kept calculating the MSE between first picture and the next pictures there after MSE kept increasing .